# Second row from MySql Database

Tags: php, mysql

I am pulling rows from a MySql DB, and I want to enter a line break on the 2nd row.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= mysql_num_rows($result); $i++)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $status = $row ['status'];
echo "$status";
    }
    if ($i % 4 == 0) {
        echo '';
    }
```

Is there a way of knowing if it is the 2nd row? Im guessing its something to do with `$i`?

Sorry if it is a silly question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. It has something to do with the `$i` variable.

If you want to enter it the 2nd row only you can evaluate `$i==2`. Also you could add it every 2nd row by evaluating `$i % 2 == 0`

This results in the following code:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= mysql_num_rows($result); $i++)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $status = $row ['status'];
    echo "$status";

    if ($i == 2){   // Or replace the evaluation with $i % 2 == 0
        echo '<br />'; //HTML linebreak
        //echo '\n'; //This is for a newline character.
    }
}
if ($i % 4 == 0) {
    echo '';
}
```

Comment: You're welcome.

And as @Scott said before: Your indenting might lead you to think the `($i % 4 == 0)` is inside of the for loop when in fact it is not.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```js
for ($i = 1; $i <= mysql_num_rows($result); $i++) {
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  $status = $row['status'];
  echo "$status";
  if ($i == 2) {
    echo "\n"; //line break
  }
}
if ($i % 4 == 0) {
  echo '';
}
```

If you want an HTML line break, use:

```
 echo "<br/>";
```

Your indenting might lead you to think the $i mod 4 is inside of the for loop when in fact it is not.

No questions are silly :)